# Can alfredo pasta be made in mixed sauce?

Tags: pasta

Is it possible to make alfredo pasta in mixed (both red and white) sauce? Is alfredo pasta the same as pasta made in white sauce?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SA! Have a look at the [Tour](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Center](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help), especially the information on [what questions to ask](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) when you get a chance. If by alfredo pasta, you mean pasta in Alfredo sauce, a quick Google search will tell you that Alfredo sauce is a white sauce with butter and cheese. Of course you can make any sauce you want, however you want. Could you clarify what you mean by "is it possible"?

Answer (score 2):

While there is hardly any reference to "Alfredo sauce" in Italy, there are plenty of pasta condiments that are based on a combination of butter and cheese.  Whether it is true or not, lore has it that in the early 1900s, a Roman restaurateur, popular with American tourists,  named his fettuccine dressed with butter and parmigiano reggiano after himself. The name was taken to America.

So, Italians would not call this "Alfredo".

You can certainly create red or white pasta condiments that contain cheese.  What you call it probably depends on how "authentic" you would like to be, and in whose authenticity you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

Alfredo sauce is a specific white sauce made with cream, butter and Parmesan cheese. Alfredo pasta is a pasta that has alfredo sauce on it specifically. There are other white sauces that aren't alfredo sauces which have other ingredients like white wine, chicken/seafood stock, with or without cheese but these would have different names. There is no such thing as a red alfredo sauce.

You can mix an alfredo and tomato based sauce, the combination can be delicious. I make a 'lazy lasagne' with pasta spirals, bolognese sauce and alfredo sauce, baked with a crispy top. I layer the sauces rather than mixing them together.

Comment: And mixed sauce isn't a mix of white and some tomato based sauce, but is, itself, a tomato based sauce, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by mixed sauce @SoumyaGhosh. You can make a sauce that has both tomato and cream in rather than making 2 sauces separately and mixing them together if that is what you mean.

Comment: As it turns out, what I meant was pink sauce and not mixed sauce. Sorry.

Comment: The claimed  'original' restaurant recipe contains no cream. The emulsion is built with warm but not hot butter, parmigiano, and starch from the pasta, some from the cooking-water, and some from the pasta itself, as it's being 'muddled' in front of the diner.